# Book about a human who substitutes for a robot substituting for a human

Tags: story-identification, robots

I don't remember much about this. A robotic look alike for the heir to the throne on some planet is ordered from an Earth-based robot making industry. They end up sending a human in stead.

I think that it might have been part of some series of books about a human and his robot friend.

Comment: It's not your book, but Nick O'Donohoe's [*Too, Too Solid Flesh*](http://www.amazon.com/Too-Solid-Flesh-Nick-ODonohoe/dp/088038767X) also has a human posing as an android.

Comment: Your description reminds me of a book, I think it was called 'My Robot Buddy', but it's been so long since I read it I can't make an answer out of this suggestion. It was, I think, an aimed at upper-elementary readers. Sound familiar or likely to anyone?

Comment: @Alyksandrei that was it!

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: Part of your question reminded me of Luis Valdez's "Los Vendidos" - where there is someone looking to purchase a robot Mexican (for diversity), who turns out to be a person (though the seller turns out to be a robot).  The similarity to your story is mostly that someone is looking to purchase a robot for a role that should be human, and the substitutions of human for robot and back again.  Obviously the last part, the series, doesn't apply.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/206751/1970s-or-80s-kids-book-series-about-friendly-android-doppelgangers (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Alyksandrei (and google) for this answer.

### The book is called "The Trouble on Janus" by Alfred Slote

The synopsis (as found on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2027298.The_Trouble_on_Janus)) reads:

> Jack and his robot buddy, Danny One, set off for the planet Janus to rescue the young King Paul from his conniving uncle.

The book was published in 1985, and is the 5th and final book in [the Robot Buddy series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Slote#Robot_Buddy_series):

> 1. My Robot Buddy (1975)
> 2. My trip to Alpha I (1978)
> 3. C.O.L.A.R. : a tale of outer space (1981)
> 4. Omega Station (1983)
> 5. The Trouble on Janus (1985)

Answer (score -1):

The original "I Robot" series by Isaac Asimov had a plot like this (nothing to do with the movie).  The only one I remember was about a robot that did not know he was a robot.

Comment: I've read *I, Robot*. This was completely different in tone and style, being a more contemporary book and obviously aimed at a lower reading level.